# Remove from list items that have fields equal to some item fields

Tags: c#, list, removeall

Here is my code:

```
public class Person
{
    public int age;
    public int grade;
    public string name;
}

List<Person> _list = new List<Person>();
// .... add lots of items
var personToRemove = new Person {age = 99, grade = 7, };
```

How to write a command that removes from `_list` all persons what have the same `age` and `grade` values that `personToRemove` has.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `.RemoveAll()` with predicate to remove all persons with matching details in `personToRemove` person object.

So your query will be.

```
int totalRemoved = _list.RemoveAll(x => x.age == personToRemove.age && x.grade == personToRemove.grade);
```

**Input:**

```
_list.Add(new Person { age = 99, grade = 7 });
_list.Add(new Person { age = 87, grade = 7 });
_list.Add(new Person { age = 57, grade = 8 });
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit:**

You can also use traditional looping for elegant way to remove match person from list of persons.

```
for (int i = _list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (_list[i].age == personToRemove.age && _list[i].grade == personToRemove.grade)
    {
        _list.RemoveAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used that, but I was really hoping there would be more elegant syntax for that.

Comment: @Narek, view **Edit:** section in answer, I think you want elegant means to be as readable also with performance.

Comment: You really think it is more elegant? :)

Comment: @Narek, As i know `RemoveAll` can be done in `O(n)` by checking the condition for n elements and moving at most n elements. and with loop can be done with `O(n^2)` to move up to n elements. but if you want it as readable then loop is best in your case but more elegant is `RemoveAll`.

Comment: @Narek, glad to see my answer was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) method to filter out the result

```
List <Person> _list = new List <Person> ();
// .... add lots of items
var personToRemove = new Person {
  age = 99, grade = 7,
};
_list.Add(new Person {
  age = 99, grade = 7
});
_list.Add(new Person {
  age = 99, grade = 7
});
_list.Add(new Person {
  age = 99, grade = 8
});
_list.Add(new Person {
  age = 100, grade = 8
});

var result = _list.Where(a => a.age != personToRemove.age || a.grade != personToRemove.grade);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking some otherways without list.RemoveAll. You can use [list.Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2) method

```
List<Person> _list = new List<Person>();

// get the list of Person you want to remove by using where.
List<Person> _Removelist = _list.Where(x => x.age == personToRemove.age && x.grade == personToRemove.grade).ToList();

List<Person> _finalList = _list.Except(_Removelist ).ToList();
```